# What is the difference between TopLink Essentials & EclipseLink

Tags: oracle, jpa, eclipselink

What is the difference between TopLink Essentials & EclipseLink, both originates from Oracle ?

Answer (score 9):

Toplink Essentials originated from Oracle and is the reference implementation of JPA 1.0.  It is a somewhat cutdown versino of Oracle's commercial TopLink product.

The code for TLE was donated to the Eclipse foundation and this became EclipseLink.  Eclipselink will be the reference implementation of JPA 2.0 as part of the EJB 3.1/Java EE 6 spec, expected to be finalized by JavaOne this year (which will also culminate with the final release of Glassfish v3).

There's really no reason to use TLE now.  EL 1.0.x is a significantly better product and incorporates all the features of Toplink (and more) and is really very good.